# Renaming C# project to map to correct configuration

Tags: c#

I have a created a C# console application that does something. Lets say its name is SampleTest. I use a config file named App.config in it. When I build this project, it creates files like SampleTest.exe, SampleTest.exe.config, etc. This is all fine.

My friend wants to execute this executable. So rather than sending SampleTest.exe and SampleTest.exe.config, I renamed the two files to DocumentManager.exe and DocumentManager.exe.config and gave it to him.

We noticed that this way, the DocumentManager.exe is not able to use the DocumentManager.exe.config file.

Please let us know what do I need to do in Visual Studio to this SampleTest project for it to generate DocumentManager.exe and DocumentManager.exe.config?

I tried renaming the SampleTest project to DocumentManager and building it but it still generates SampleTest.exe

Comment: Right click on the project -> properties -> Application. Now choose the name that you want for "Assembly name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Renaming the Assembly**

Renaming the project on it's own is likely not going to be enough for what you are trying to accomplish. You'll need to ensure that you update the name of your assembly and namespace as well, which can be done through **Properties > Application > Assembly name** :

[image]

Changing the assembly name will change the names of your executable and .config files generated when building the project. It's probably worth changing your default namespace as well, just to keep things consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You have to rename assembly. To fix this please do the following:

1. Navigate to project folder and find `SampleTest.csproj` file.
2. Open that file in some text editor like Notepad++. Find elements:

```xml
<RootNamespace>SampleTest</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>SampleTest</AssemblyName>
```

3. Rename their values into:

```xml
<RootNamespace>DocumentManager</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>DocumentManager</AssemblyName>`.
```

4. Build your project and you will see new `DocumentManager.exe.config` and new `DocumentManager.exe` files.

Or you can change Namespace and AssemblyName trough UI by navigating to  Properties > Application > Assembly Name.

Comment: While this does work, a beginner is going to be overwhelmed by dealing directly with the csproj file. I know I was. I'd recommend using the tooling in Visual Studio unless it's not working.

Comment: @Cameron It depends on how you developing! I started to work with `.csproj` files early only because my position required that and I encourage other developers to try this method. So, this I my way :) Anyway, I agree with you that is easier trough UI.